# Handle Authentication in Ajax Interaction with JSF and Apache Shiro

Tags: ajax, jsf, shiro

I'm developing JSF application with Apache Shiro. Everything is OK except that when the the UI interacts with the server via ajax the web reflects nothing. how can I configure the application, so that the user is redirected to the login page when the UI interact with the server through ajax.

Can somebody help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you found your answer but you won't like the one I have:-)  Here's a link for you to look at:  [JSF 2 + Spring 3 + Shiro - Session Timeout doesn't redirect to login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099262/jsf-2-spring-3-shiro-session-timeout-doesnt-redirect-to-login-page).  I've got the Shiro side doing what it's supposed to but I'm stuck on how to get the client to handle the ajax response since JSF uses tags.  In our case, we attempt to submit a commandbutton and some Shiro process says you aren't authenticated which then redirects you to the login page.  Where does the Ajax response code go - commandbutton or login page?  Maybe you have a better grasp of Ajax and JS than I hopefully this link will get you pointed in the right direction.  Let me know if you find an elegant way to handle this!!