# JSF 2 + Spring 3 + Shiro - Session Timeout doesn't redirect to login page

Tags: spring, jsf-2, shiro

I have this JSF 2.0/Spring app that added Apache Shiro to and a redirect after session timeout never occurs when a user clicks on a command button or triggers an AJAX request.  It does work when they refresh the browser.  This is happening in all browsers.  Here's my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
        <property name="loginUrl" value="/index.faces"/>
        <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
                <value>
                        /* = authc 
                </value>
        </property>
</bean>
<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
        <property name="realm" ref="opacsRealm" />
</bean>

<bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="sha512Matcher" class="org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher">

        <property name="hashAlgorithmName" value="SHA-256" />
        <property name="hashIterations" value="1024" />
</bean>



<bean id="opacsRealm" class="org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="authenticationQuery" 
                value="select PASSWORD, SALT from SEC_USERS where NAME = ?" />
        <property name="userRolesQuery" 
                value="SELECT ROLE_NAME FROM SEC_USERS_ROLES WHERE USER_NAME = ?" />
        <property name="permissionsQuery" 
                value="SELECT permission FROM SEC_ROLES_PERMISSIONS WHERE ROLE_NAME = ?" />
        <property name="permissionsLookupEnabled" value="true" />
        <property name="saltStyle" value="COLUMN" />
        <property name="credentialsMatcher" ref="sha512Matcher"/>
</bean>
```

Am I doing something wrong in the setup?  The web.xml looks like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<session-config>
  <!-- web.xml expects the session timeout in minutes: -->
  <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Just for kicks, I changed the authc to use a custom FormAuthenticationFilter and overrode the redirectToLogin method and added back the code in the parent class.  No change but the log statement I added to the method did print, so the redirect is happening but the browser never redirects unless a screen refresh is done.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I can tell you that this is likely working as designed.  With this configuration, when the session times out, the authc filter will redirect any ajax request to the login page.  However, in order for your page to be refreshed to the login page, the javascript would need to interpret the 302 response and refresh the page.  This has been discussed on the Shiro user list recently, and I believe the asker found a suitable solution: http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/Web-Filter-to-return-HTTP-status-code-td7577672.html

Comment: I just read that thanks.  He hasn't replied with his solution so I'll see if I can figure it out from his post.

Answer (score 2):

Just replied to your mail. What is happening is that the redirect is handled seamlessly by the browser in your Ajax call so Shiro does redirect to the login page and the end result of your Ajax request is the HTML content of the login page, which isn't really what you want!

The gist of how to work around this is to add a (custom) Shiro filter to your Ajax Api urls that checks the Subject for being authenticated and instead of redirecting to login return a response that your Ajax request understands to indicate that the user is not logged in. Client side handling of this response can then do a redirect to the login page (or perhaps the same page because Shiro will then redirect to login but can be configured to remember where you were trying to go and hence take the user back to the correct page upon successful login).

My filter implementation returns Http code 401 along with "WWW-Authentication" header and a custom "challenge scheme" (if you did a basic authentication challenge then the browser would pop up its basic authentication dialog - there is already a Shiro filter that does this).

In your Ajax call you need to detect this response, currently I have a clunky error callback that does it BUT I think it should be possible to modify the JavaScript library (JQuery, whatever) to handle this seamlessly.

Comment: That part did work and I have the ajax component redirecting to the login page.  The last issue related to this is page refreshing.  I can use the onunload to catch a page refresh but if it occurs after a session timeout, the page is gone.  I've placed alerts in the page to popup whenever certain events occur like DOM refresh, but nothing pops up when I page refresh after a session timeout.  Is there any way to catch this?  Here's some code snippets I've tried:

Comment: Tried to format the code but I forgot how:               jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var request = jQuery.ajax({
      url: "viewJobActivity.faces",
      type: "POST"
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
     alert('done');
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
  });

Comment: Another way I tried:      `jQuery.ajax(
    {
     // Define AJAX properties.
     method: "get",
     url: "viewJobActivity.faces",
     // Define the succss method.
     success: function(){
      alert( "Success!" );
     },
     // Define the error method.
     error: function( objAJAXRequest, strError ){
      alert("Error! Type: " + strError);
     }
    }
    );`

Comment: For those that are using Apache Shiro and Primefaces to handle session timeouts: jquery plugin called sessionTimeout.  What this plugin does is wait until a preset amount of time and then display a dialog warning the user that their session is about to timeout.  They can then go ahead and logout or stay on the page, which resets the timer.  If the user doesn't do anything, then the page eventually redirects (time set by you) to the login page.  My logout page does nothing but call the managed bean to call the Shiro logout method and then return "window.location.replace('login.faces')".

Comment: I know the plugin doesn't really handle session timeouts but it does enable an elegant solution to stale sessions which if done right can perform the Shiro logout which terminates the session and unauthenicates the user.